# What does FC_REFLECT do?

Tags: eosio-code

In most of the system contracts of EOSIO, I found FC_REFLECT function repeatedly used. What does this function actually do?
I wonder if any of you can tell the answer for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FC_REFLECT is not used in contracts/system contracts.

It's used in EOSIO itself (the tools and programs to run a Node), especially in plugins and libraries.

FC_REFLECT is part of reflect.hpp, a collection of typedefs and macros to provide *reflection*.

Reflection or introspection in programming means that a program knows its own structure and can possibly modify or copy it - and that's what FC_REFLECT is for.

Comment: What is the reason for the prefix "FC" in FC_REFLECT?

Comment: @Shravan FC = Fast-Compiling. It's part of the FC-Library.